# Euler characteristic of cyclic quotients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $T$ is a smooth complex projective algebraic surface, such that the finite cyclic group 
$\mathbb{Z_n}$ acts on it. Also, suppose that $S$ is another complex projective algebraic surface (not necessarily smooth) such that $S$ is birational to $T/\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. What can one say about the relation between the (sheaf theoretic) Euler characteristics of $T$ and $S$?
in particular, can we claim that the Euler characteristic of $T$, $e(T)$ is greater than or equal to $ne(S)$?

Comment: what is the "sheaf theoretic Euler characteristic"?

Comment: I mean the Euler characteristic of the structure sheaf as defined in Hartshorne p.230. 

Comment: Let $T$ be an abelian surface with $\{\pm1\}$ acting it. The quotient is a singular K3-surface and a resolution is a non-singular K3-surface. Both of them have Euler characteristic $2$ and $T$ has Euler characteristic $0$ so the answer to the last question is no. 

Comment: In the case where $S$ is the minimal resolution of $T$, this is pretty classical stuff and it is related in some fascinating way to continuous fractions. You need of course to know *how* your group acts (there are several inequivalent actions of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$). For a (by no means original) treatment, have a look at Sections $2$ and $3$ of my paper with E. Mistretta "Standard isotrivial fibrations with $p_g=q=1$ - II" (it is on the arXiv), in particular at Proposition 3.5.  

Comment: Dear Francesco. Thank you for your answer and also for introducing the paper. It was very helpful for me. 